# IronPython 2.7.4 Exposing Application Object Model

Tags: c#, hosting, ironpython

I'm trying to run the basic hosting "Exposing Application Object Model" C# example from the IronPython doc. scope.SetVariable(...)  does not seem to be enough to expose method. 
object is exposed, but can't access it's methods. Following works with older IronPython 1.

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;

public class CallingDotNet {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();

        scope.SetVariable("my_object_model", new CallingDotNet());

        engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("my_object_model.Foo(42)").Execute(scope);
    }

    public void Foo(int arg) {
        Console.WriteLine("You gave me a {0}", arg);
    }
}
```

Getting following exception wwith IronPython 2.7:

```
'CallingDotNet' object has no attribute 'Foo'

   at IronPython.Runtime.Binding.PythonGetMemberBinder.FastErrorGet`1.GetError(CallSite site, TSelfType target, CodeContext context)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope)
```

So how should I expose the object with IronPython 2.7  ?

Edit : Actually the I'm trying to run following code, I guess I'm getting confused with namespace/imports:

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;
namespace IronTestHosting
{
    class Program
    {
        public class CallingDotNet
        {
            public static void Run(string[] args)
            {
                var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                var scope = engine.CreateScope();

                scope.SetVariable("my_object_model", new CallingDotNet());
                engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("my_object_model.Foo(42)").Execute(scope);
            }

            public void Foo(int arg)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You gave me a {0}", arg);
            }
        }        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallingDotNet.Run(args);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it. What do you get if you replace the python code with `print dir(my_object_model)`?

Comment: You are absolutely right @Cobbal !? when I put this exact code in fresh solution it works fine !?! I'm confused now ... will post my exact code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `Program` public as well as the inner class. For reasons I'm not fully sure of, all containing classes must be public or IronPython won't be able to interact with your class.